# Is it possible to use laravel yajra datatabl without specifying columns in js?

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using Yajra datatable with laravel. I need search and and export features of datatable but  need to draw the  table in blade through php code. I tried this and got this error >'aoColumns[srcCol] is undefined'.

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
                bPaginate: false,
                serverSide: false,
                afnFiltering: false,
                bSort: false,
                order: [1, 'desc'],
                buttons: dataTableExportButtons(__('Truck Ageing'), {refreshCallBack: false})
            });
```

above is my js code and there is no mismatch in count of th and td